# How to find the range in $f(x)=\operatorname{arccsc} \left(\sqrt{2x-x^2}\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

> Let the real function:
>
> $$f(x)=\operatorname{arccsc} \left(\sqrt{2x-x^2}\right)$$
>
> Find the range of that function.
>
> According to my workbook, the official answer to this question is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

But how to get there?

What I attempted to do is:

First get the domain. For the arccosecant function the domain is:

$x\leq -1 \lor x\geq 1$

Given this situation it arises two choices:

$\sqrt{2x-x^2} \leq -1$

This will yield an empty set as there cannot be a solution in the $\mathbb{R}$.

The other choice would be $\emptyset\,\cup \sqrt{2x-x^2}\geq 1$

This would be:

$2x-x^2\geq 1$

$x^2-2x+1 \leq 0$

$(x-1)^2 \leq 0$

The latter yields two choices, that the left side of the inequality it can be lesser than zero or equal to zero.

This cannot be lesser than zero in the $\mathbb{R}$ thus this part is $\emptyset$ and since the symbol denotes a union. The other choice must be:

$(x-1)^2=0$

In this case the only choice is:

$x=1$

Then the domain in $\mathbb{R}$ is $1$. Just one element.

Therefore all that it remains is to evaluate on the function and see if it complies with the official answer.

By doing this I'm getting:

$f(1)=\csc^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2\cdot 1-(1)^2}\right)=\csc^{-1}(1)$

Then it would be $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

And I believe this might be the intended approach. Is my method the right way to solve this?. Can someone help me here?.

Since I got this problem in my precalculus workbook the approach which I was looking to use is someone free from derivatives.

Comment: $$2x-x^2=1-(x-1)^2\le 1$$

Comment: The only $x-$values you can plug into $y=\text{arccsc}(x)$ are those belonging to $I=(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$. The only time $\sqrt{2x-x^2}$ belongs to $I$ occurs when $x=1$. This means the *domain* of $y=\text{arccsc}\Big(\sqrt{2x-x^2}\Big)$ is $\{1\}$ so its range is $$\text{arccsc}\Big(\sqrt{2\cdot 1-1^2}\Big)=\pi/2$$

Answer (score 1):

The range of $2x-x^2=1-(x-1)^2$ is obviously $(-\infty,1]$ so that of its square root is $[0,1]$.

As a cosecant is $\ge1$ or $\le-1$, the range of $f$ is $\{\csc^{-1}(1)\}$.

Comment: There is no real need to care about the domain.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

The domain of $ g:  x\mapsto \sqrt{2x-x^2} $ is $ [0,2] $.

$$\forall x\in(0,2)\; g'(x)=\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}$$

$$\implies \forall x\in [0,2]\;\;g(x)\le g(1)$$

$$\implies \forall x\in[0,2]\;\; g(x)\in[0,1]$$

Answer (score 0):

If y=f(x)

$$\csc^2 y=  x (2-x)$$

Subtract 1 and re-arranging
$$ \tan^2 y = -\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

At x=1 , y = $\pi/2$ only... because

At x=0 , y is imaginary